# How to detect flashblocker?

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm using [flash uploader](http://swfupload.org/) and I'd like to be able to find out whether a flash blocker is present (activated) for me to able to let user know that he needs flash.

There is a native support in browsers for letting users know they don't have flash installed. But how to deal with this ?

I was searching in global Javascript object whether the flashblocker is exposing something, but I can't find anything.

Any idea how to deal with this ?

Comment: `<embed>` tags can have accompanying `<noembed>` tags.  You could try using that.

Comment: I've never used flash, I don't know what that means much... The uploader uses javascript to load the flash. If there is flashblocker, the flash doesn't load up. But there might be other reasons why it doesn't work so I want to know exactly what to tell the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/flashblockdetector/

Answer (score 1):

The code.google.com link seems dead.

I found this:
https://github.com/browserstack/flashblock-detector

but haven't tried it in IE 11.

It does navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE'), which isn't in my userAgent string running IE 11.